# How to assign value to table view cell in completion handler Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

This question may be asked because of my ignorance regarding completion and how to use them properly, but I have been researching and just couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have a function that gets user data from database, I then want to assign values that I got from the database to my table view cell. If I don't have completion in my AssignValueToUserObject method, my table view cell is called before I actually get the values which results in an error.

So I found that completion was the way to go and it was working for me so far, but now that I am using table view cell, I can't actually call the table view method manually inside the completion, so I don't know how I can get the data using the method, and then assign the values to the table view cell.

Here is my method:

```
extension MoneyGroupViewController {

public func AssignValueToUserObject(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Get user unique id
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        print("Could not get user id")
        return
    }

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [self] snapshot in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            
            user.first_name = dictionary["first_name"] as! String
            user.last_name = dictionary["last_name"] as! String
            user.email = dictionary["email"] as! String
            user.profile_picture = dictionary["profile_picture"] as? String
            
            completion() //call once the action is done
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
} // End AssignValueToUserObject Method
} // End extension
```

And here is my table view cell function which is my view controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = groupTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MoneyGroupTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MoneyGroupTableViewCell
    
    cell.userName.text = userArray[indexPath.row].first_name + " " + userArray[indexPath.row].last_name
    
    if (user.profile_picture != "") {
        let url = URL(string: user.profile_picture!)!
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, _, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = max(cell.userImage.frame.width,  cell.userImage.frame.height)/2
                cell.userImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
                cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }).resume() // End URLSession
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

And finally, here is how I am calling the method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    AssignValueToUserObject {
        // I should call the table view function here but I don't know how
    }
   }
```

**Update**

Yes my cell should display user's info (first name, last name, email, and an optional profile picture).

I potentially want to add all of users that are in a "group" in my userArray, but right now I am not implementing that functionality, and I just have the same user in userArray to test my table view.

So userArray should only have the same user right now, but my problem still persists, I don't know how I can get user's info from the database **before** the table view cell call.

Comment: Show the definition of your `userArray` and how you populate it. The short answer is that you **can't** fetch from your database or download an image before your table view s ready to display. You need to display an empty table view, or cells with placeholder information, until you are able to load the data you need.

Comment: If your goal is to display a list of users and their info, do not write it to work with a single user first, and then go back and change it to manage multiple users later. There are gotchas involved in handling a list of users that will bite you later if you do that. You will wind up needing a total rewrite.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I will take your advice and will try to manage the multiple users first. So how would I implement displaying an empty table view or cells with placeholder until I load the data? Do you mind posting an answer that shows that?

Comment: Firebase has several different database services.  So using the firebase tag doesn't tell us which service you are using.

Comment: I am not sure what are the different services you are referring to, but I am using real time database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to use Completion Block here.

Simply use UITableView’s instance Method `reloadData()` whenever you need your tableview to reload its contents.
This could be when your data model changes.

Calling `tableView.reloadData()` will run all the datasource methods including:

`cellForItemAt:` and `numberOfRows:`

In this case, I assume you should have User’s Struct/Class something like this:

```
struct UserData
{
    var first_name : String = ""
    var last_name : String = ""
    var email : String = ""
    var profile_picture : String = ""
}
```

Try Doing It This Way:

```
class YourClass : UIViewController {

//Create an Empty User (As you want to implement with single user first)
let user : UserData = UserData()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   AssignValueToUserObject()

    }
```

Method:

```
extension MoneyGroupViewController {

public func AssignValueToUserObject() {
    // Get user unique id
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        print("Could not get user id")
        return
    }

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] snapshot in
        
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            user.first_name = dictionary["first_name"] as! String
            user.last_name = dictionary["last_name"] as! String
            user.email = dictionary["email"] as! String
            user.profile_picture = dictionary["profile_picture"] as? String
        }

        //Reload Your Tableview once you're done Fetching Data from Firestore
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self?.YOURTABLEVIEW.reloadData()
     }
    }, withCancel: nil)
 } // End AssignValueToUserObject Method
}
```

Tableview's `cellForRowAt:`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = groupTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MoneyGroupTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MoneyGroupTableViewCell
    
    cell.userName.text = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
  
    //Note: You should use "SDWebImage" or "Kingfisher" Library for async image downloading
    if let url = URL(string: user.profile_picture)
    {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, _, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = max(cell.userImage.frame.width,  cell.userImage.frame.height)/2
                cell.userImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
                cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }).resume() // End URLSession
    }
    return cell
}
```

Note:

1. At first Tableview is going to Load but with Empty Data. (Eg: Empty user)
2. `AssignValueToUserObject()` will fill user object with some Data.
3. `reloadData()` is going to call, which will Reload Tableview & Populate Data in Cell with New Data.

Comment: this answer is so close to what I want, but when I implement it, I first get the user name without their profile picture, and after 2 seconds, my cell is filled with a random box and everything else disappears. Do you know why I am having this issue?

Comment: I think some constraints are missing of your ImageView inside Tableview Cell. Try with Fixed Height & Width for ImageView, it should work!

Comment: Calling `reloadData()` works, but it is overkill, and will lead to a sluggish user experience. That causes every cell in the table view to be reloaded. you are much better off reloading the specific cells that need it, using `reloadRows(at:with:)` (and passing in an array of the IndexPaths that need updating.)

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about this wrong.

You should not try to assign things to your table view cells. You should save your newly fetched data to your model, and then tell your table view that it needs to update. If you have loaded new content for an existing cell, use `reloadRows(at:with:)` to tell the table view to reload the cell for that data. The table view will then ask it's data source for an updated cell. The data source will build the updated cell from your updated data, and it will display correctly.

Note that if you call `reloadRows(at:with:)` from inside your completion handler, you should wrap the call in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()` so that it is executed on the main thread.

### Edit

Looking at your code, you have a number of problems.

What is your table view supposed to display? Cells with info about users? (first and last name, email address, and profile picture?

What does your userArray contain? An array of structs of what type? UserInfo? edit your question to include that information.

It looks like you actually have 2 separate async operations to complete before you are able to display everything about a user: You need to do a database fetch to get info about the user (including the URL to their profile picture, and then you need to make a network call (to `URLSession.shared.dataTask` to download your image.

Your `AssignValueToUserObject` function appears to always read info for a single user, but your code that configures table view cells seems to fetch data from an array `userArray`, **EXCEPT for the ** image URL in `user.profile_picture`, which will always be for the single user you reference in `AssignValueToUserObject`.

In short, your code is pretty jumbled up, and without a clear description of what you are trying to do, we can't help you un-jumble it.

Comment: Okay, could you please show me how I would save the data to my model? This is the bit I am struggling with, should I do that inside the completion in AssignValueToUserObject method or somewhere else?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. You need to provide a lot more information before we can help you (And please edit your question to clarify rather than adding comments.)

Comment: Done, let me know if you need any extra info.